# Sum numbers in multiple files

Tags: shell

I have about 200 files with only one column of numbers.

How can I add the numbers and replace in place?

```
File 1
2
5
8
1

File 2
1
2
3
5
```

It seems I cannot use `awk inplace` due to the older GNU version.

Is there any other option to do `inplace` replacement for multiple files?

If you could please help me with the correct command?

My files are in a directory `./Directory/*.csv`

Comment: I'm not sure I understood, if you want to sum you would probably want to add the sum at the end of the file and not replace some text in the middle, am I right?

Comment: Actually I want to replace the file content with just the result. Is that doable?

Comment: I think adding the result at the bottom would be more beneficial in terms of data integrity.

Comment: You could very easily write a script called `inplace` that performs an arbitrary filter on a file and replaces the file with that filter's output.  eg `trap 'rm -f "$TMP"' 0; TMP=$(mktemp); f="$1"; shift; "$@" < "$f" > "$TMP"; cat "$TMP" > "$f"`

Answer (score 0):

This is adding the sum at the bottom, the downside is that you can only run it once:

`find -name '*' | xargs -I % bash -c "awk 'BEGIN{x=0} {x+=$ 1} END{print x}' % >> %"`

(Do not remove any of the `>` symbols, it will put a zero instead of the content)

In order to replace the file content completely we will need to save it somewhere and then put it in the file, otherwise the content of the file will be deleted completely.